# php array data collect from middle if range match

Tags: php, arrays

How can I collect array from B1->price[4] to E1->price[6] dynamically.

```
Array
(
[A1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 3
        [duration] => 1
    )

[B1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 4
        [duration] => 3
    )

[C1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 5
        [duration] => 2

    )
[D1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 6
        [duration] => 3

    )
[E1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 6
        [duration] => 2

    )
[F1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 7
        [duration] => 3

    )
)
```

```
Array
(
[A1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 3
        [duration] => 1
    )

[B1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 4
        [duration] => 3
    )

[C1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 5
        [duration] => 2

    )
[D1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 6
        [duration] => 3

    )
[E1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 6
        [duration] => 2

    )
[F1] => Array
    (
        [price] => 7
        [duration] => 3

    )
)
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: By writing some code

Comment: I just edit my question

Comment: @user1130537 You just posted the array twice. *why?* Show us your effort (pseudo code or code or some research which you have done).

Comment: What is `price[4]` and `price[6]`?  those are not arrays you can't use an index with them

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your result

```
    $arrayName = 
        array(
        'A1' => array('price' => 3,'duration' => 1),
        'B1' => array('price' => 4,'duration' => 3),
        'C1' => array('price' => 5,'duration' => 2),
        'D1' => array('price' => 6,'duration' => 3),
        'E1' => array('price' => 6,'duration' => 2),
        'F1' => array('price' => 7,'duration' => 3)
        );
echo '<pre>';
print_r(array_slice($arrayName, 1, -1)) ;
echo '</pre>';
```